# Use Geomagic touch for controlling 7 dof robot in rvizz or gazebo

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am new in ros and trying to implement a simulation framework to control a 7dof robot using geomagic touch device. I have studied basics of ros and simulation in gazebo and rviz. Can anyone provide me with guidelines that how should I proceed ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244932/use-geomagic-touch-for-controlling-7-dof-robot-in-rvizz-or-gazebo/) by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2016-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before using Gazebo, you need to create a URDF model of you 7 DOF robot. You can follow through the tutorials of [Gazebo and ROS](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=connect_ros).

Test your model works with Gazebo by using [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control) for the controllers.

Then you will have to map the geomagic touch device to some sort of control input for ros_control controllers.

If you are satisfied with your simulation in Gazebo, you will need to replace the simulated robot with your robot hardware. This includes creating a joint state publisher and controllers for your 7 DOF robot.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2016-10-04**:
thnx alot for your suggestions Josh .. I will try it .. cheers :)